# Exp:resso Store - Limit Stock not working in Store 2

Tags: expresso-store, dynamic, out-of-stock, classes

My client needs to be able to manually set a product 'out of stock'. In store v1 they could do this simply by ticking the limit stock check box on the relevant product page (against the relevant product modifier). This doesn't seem to work in store 2.

We are controlling what is shown using the dynamic class options eg:

`<span class="store_product_in_stock">IN STOCK</span><span class="store_product_out_of_stock">OUT OF STOCK</span>`

However no matter what we set in the admin, the product is being shown as 'in stock'.

Here is a grab of our admin:
[image]

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Store and EE are you using? Also on the product page can you check the error console to make sure you are not getting any JS errors?

Comment: Are you running Store v2.0.3? Also have you tried ticking "limit stock" and explicitly setting the stock level to '0'?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Store v2.0.3, EE v2.7.1. Loading jQuery 1.8.0 in the `<head>` of my page. No console errors. I've explicitly set stock to zero for several SKUs. When I click on modifiers, the price updates exactly as it should, but combinations that should be out of stock fail to flip `store_product_out_of_stock` to `display:block;`.

Comment: FWIW, `{store_product_stock}` doesn't seem to output anything. I'm guessing this is the correct usage:

     <p>Stock level: <span class="store_product_stock"></span></p>

Comment: FWIW again, store_product_sku _does_ work fine: `<p>SKU of this variation: <span class="store_product_sku"></span></p>`

Comment: I'm using EE v2.7.1 and Store 2.0.3. No errors in the console. We have tried both ticking 'limit stock' and explicitly entering 0 with the same (not working) result.